# What is the difference between "compose of" and "composed with"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference

More precisely, I want to understand "composed with us in mind" in the following passage.

[image]

Roughly, I think that maybe "composed with us in mind" means "made by our mind".

Am I wrong? What does "composed with us in mind" mean? And what is the difference between "composed of" and "composed with"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Composed with” is not a phrasal verb.

To do something “with *x* in mind” means perform that action toward some explicit purpose or end.

To say reality is a “work of art composed with us in mind” means that there is an artist (God?) who is composing reality as if it were art, and that artist is doing so on behalf of humanity (“us”).

Answer (score 3):

The comparison isn't actually between "composed of" and "composed with", it's between "composed of" and "composed". In brief, "with us in mind" is a separate adverbial phrase that is not attached directly to "composed".

To illustrate, these are correct sentences:

- "With that in mind, I composed the essay."
- "I composed the essay with him in mind."
- "This is the essay, which I composed with him in mind."
- "With that in mind, I wrote the essay."

There are two meanings of the word "compose" that are relevant here. Meaning 1 is "to create or craft (a work of art or writing)", which is the meaning in the phrase "composed with us in mind". Meaning 2 is "to make up or constitute", which is the meaning in the phrase "composed of".